# File not found error when trying to load Librosa's example file

Tags: python, pycharm, file-not-found, librosa

I'm writing my first program using Librosa so I copied some code from their documentation to see if I could get it working. I'm getting a file not found error when trying to load the example file and I can't figure out why. I've found a few people who said they've had a no backend error (https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/743, https://github.com/beetbox/audioread/issues/54) and I'm wondering if that's related to my problem? I'm using PyCharm if that makes a difference

Here's my code:

```py
import librosa

filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
print(y)
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/owner/PycharmProjects/SongVisualizer/SongVisualizer.py", line 11, in <module>
    y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
  File "C:\Users\owner\PycharmProjects\SongVisualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 119, in load
    with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
  File "C:\Users\owner\PycharmProjects\SongVisualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py", line 107, in audio_open
    backends = available_backends()
  File "C:\Users\owner\PycharmProjects\SongVisualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py", line 86, in available_backends
    if ffdec.available():
  File "C:\Users\owner\PycharmProjects\SongVisualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread\ffdec.py", line 108, in available
    creationflags=PROC_FLAGS,
  File "C:\Users\owner\PycharmProjects\SongVisualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread\ffdec.py", line 94, in popen_multiple
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced with same problem and changed the line **return subprocess.Popen(cmd, *args, **kwargs)** with **return subprocess.Popen(cmd, *args, **kwargs, shell = True)** in ffdec.py. It works, but executing the code through the shell is not recommended. More details can be found from: [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) and adding it to my PATH variable. Librosa's audio module requires FFmpeg to load and manipulate audio.